# copy row to a new dataframe if it's not six consecutive

Tags: python, pandas

I have data frame that is like the following

```
index a  royal 
1     1  king
2     1  king
3     1  king
4     1  king
5     1  king
6     1  king
7     2  queen
8     2  queen 
9     2  queen
10    2  king
```

I want to copy all row 7-10 to a new data frame and remove it from the original because index 7-10 is not six consecutive numbers and also do not belong to the same category. My logic is like this.

```
starting_position=0
tracking=0

    for counter, category in enumerate (df['royal']):
       if df['royal'][counter].shift==df['royal'][counter]:
          if df['a'][0].shift==df['a'][0]:
             counter+=1
             if counter!=6:
                df2=df.loc[start_position:counter]
                df.drop([start_position,counter])
                tracking=0 
             elif counter==6:
                tracking=0
          else:
             df2=df.loc[start_position:counter]
             df.drop([start_position,counter])
             tracking=0
        else:
             df2=df.loc[start_position:counter]
             df.drop([start_position,counter])
             tracking=0
```

This pretty terrible code. I believe there is a way to do it with cumsum but I just can't figure it out. I'm also trying groupby and cumsum but there are way too many error outputs. Ideally I want to have this output

DF1

```
 index    a  royal 
    1     1  king
    2     1  king
    3     1  king
    4     1  king
    5     1  king
    6     1  king
```

DF2

```
 index    a  royal 
    7     2  queen
    8     2  queen 
    9     2  queen
    10    2  king
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`filter` with `groupby`

```
df.groupby('a').filter(lambda x : len(x)<6)
Out[173]: 
   index  a  royal
6      7  2  queen
7      8  2  queen
8      9  2  queen
9     10  2   king
df.groupby('a').filter(lambda x : len(x)>=6)
Out[174]: 
   index  a royal
0      1  1  king
1      2  1  king
2      3  1  king
3      4  1  king
4      5  1  king
5      6  1  king
```

Comment: Classy and elegant, @Wen, as usual. Have an upd00t.

Comment: Thank you, I thought I had to use cumsum for this.

Comment: @Longroadahead yw happy coding